# Reach LXC container from a virtualbox guest on the same host

Tags: networking, iptables, virtualbox, lxc

**Context**

- I develop websites on my Ubuntu laptop (Ubuntu 13.04 64b).
- Each site runs within a dedicated LXC container¹ on network 10.0.3.x
- I sometimes need to reach those sites from a virtualbox guest running Windows²

It used to work "out of the box", but a few weeks ago, it just stopped.
I guess after an Ubuntu update but was it a LXC or a Virtualbox or even a "network stuff" update ? I can't tell since I don't run those tests every day.

*¹ To fake various and complex platforms and only use ressources I actually need.*

*² To test them under Windows browsers.*

**The question :**

How should I setup my Virtualbox/LXC/host network configurations to reach the websites on LXC containers from the Virtualbox guest ?

**What I have done so far**

My current virtualbox setup is to have 2 network cards.

- A bridge on `wlan0` (to access the Internet)
- A bridge on LXC virtual card `lxcbr0` (to access the containers)

> A Weird thing :
>   I can ping LXC containers from the Windows VM, but I can't access them in HTTP (browsers or telnet on port 80).
>
> Only actually started containers responds to ping.

I tried a bunch of others setups but I am more "guessing" than understanding what is going on.

**My current workarround**

I setup a port forward on my host with iptables, as I would do to make a container reachable on the whole network (it's actually what it does).

When I do so I can reach the forwarded container from the Windows VM.

But this is definitly not a clean solution :

- I can only access one container at the time (or I have to use different ports)
- I need to reconfigure iptables any time I switch project
- I actually give access to the container to the outside world
- I need to have an active LAN or WAN connection
- I can hardly use domain names anymore (I have a host file in Windows matching container's ip)

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of user228273 i could find configuration that solved the problem:
First I created a tap interface named tap0, and I brought it up:

```
ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
ip link set tap0 up
```

if one of the previous command fails, it is probably because you already have a `tap0` interface. Use the command

```
ip link show
```

to assess the situation, and eventually change the interface name.
Now you can add the `tap0` interface to the default bridge that under Ubuntu is named `lxcbr0`.

```
brctl addif lxcbr0 tap0
```

Then i configured my VirtualBox to use a "Bridged Adapter" on the interface `tap0` as shown below:

[image: VirtualBox configuration]

And then the VirtualBox instance and the LXCs can "see" each others.

**2019 Update** :
If you're using NetworkManager you can make this addition using nmcli:

```
nmcli connection add type tun ifname tap0 con-name tap0 mode tap master lxcbr0
```

Comment: Well, I can't really test and validate your solution since I switched to Docker a long time ago, but nice answer for those who would come accross the same issue in the future, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem. Almost certainly the "fault" of VirtualBox, which seems to do bridged networking it's own way, probably to remain consistent across the various platforms (Mac, Solaris and that other one). Evidence:

- VBox bridged network interfaces *do not* appear in "brctl show" (as do LXC veth's)
- documentation has: "VirtualBox uses a device driver on your host system that filters data from your physical network adapter"

Really weird that ICMP is getting through, but TCP (and likely others) ain't...

However, documentation also has "you can still use TAP interfaces for certain advanced setups", so I investigated attaching a new TAP to my bridge:

```
# ip tuntap add mode tap
# brctl addif brY tapX
# ip link set tapX up
```

Then adjusted the VBox network settings to use tapX instead of brY and it all came good (after rebooting the guest).

Experimented with two guests sharing the same tapX, not sure it worked so well. Probably safest to use one tap for each VBox guest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the target but can not access applications there then it is an iptables issue, almost sure.

My guess is during update process you got  the system flag `"net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1"` checked ON in `/etc/systcl.conf`.

If so, I would not drop it OFF, but revise the iptables setup instead.

Comment: I don't have this param in the file nor in `/etc/sysctl.d/*`.
Also, `sudo iptables --list` return no rules on laptop startup with or without a container started. I guess the magic happens somewhere else (netwok-manager stuff ?). I am using Ubuntu 13.04, I'll edit my question to add that precision.

Comment: I can not imagine such kind of magic except VirtualBox introduces very special networking tricks. What type of network does the VirtualBox use?